# Headphone amplifier for Camera without audio jack

Tags: amplifier, audio, microphone

I am thinking about a project for my camera.
A problem that often occurs with cameras and I haven't found a solution yet is, that there is an external microphone input but no audio output to monitor the sound.

Could I "split" the signal that comes from the microphone and feed it into the camera but also to an audio amplifier like this:
[amplifier](https://www.amazon.de/Audioverst%C3%A4rker-Leistungsverst%C3%A4rkerplatine-PAM8403-Digital-Verst%C3%A4rker/dp/B07YQGB15D/ref=sr_1_5?__mk_de_DE=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&crid=FY717IO2369H&keywords=arduino%20amplifier&qid=1689171309&sprefix=arduino%20amplifier%2Caps%2C219&sr=8-5)

Would this reduce the quality of the recorded audio?
Also can I safely use any headphones on such an amp (like the ones that come with Apple products)?

Answer (score 1):

If the amplifier has a high input impedance, running the signal from the microphone to *both* the camera and the amplifier, e.g., through a Y-connection cable, should not noticeably degrade the signal.

That said, here are some *caveats*.

- Realize that you are monitoring the signal from the mic, *not* the actual recording. Though this would give a relative perception of echoes, *location* background noise, etc., it would *not* show issues during recording such as excessive compression, *electronic* noise in the camera, distortion due to high amplitude, etc.
- The amplifier you suggest is [class D](https://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/articles/class-d-audio-amplifiers.html), which is more efficient than linear amplification, *but* it uses high-speed digital switching. If some of the switching transients were to leak into the camera sound input, it *might* affect the audio quality... or might not. If you're just driving low-power headphones, think about using lower-power linear preamplifier.
- Be careful to avoid damage to the camera or introducing hum due to power supply issues. Perhaps run the preamp from a separate battery.

Comment: indeed I didnt think about the point that I dont hear the actually recorded sound. Have to think about that again. I will definetly use a seperate power supply

Comment: BTW, some camera models can use the USB port for audio out: https://www.dpreview.com/forums/thread/3560514 , https://www.dpreview.com/opinion/5986041583/opinion-fujifilm-s-decision-to-omit-the-headphone-jack-on-the-x-t4-is-a-mistake , https://cheesycam.com/usb-audio-monitoring-adapter-magic-lantern/